# How do I fix the drivers not working on my HP Stream 7?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, windows-installation, touchscreen, x86

A HP Stream 7 needed reinstalling Windows 10.

After the successful install, I noticed that several drivers are missing:

- Audio
- Wi-Fi
- Bluetooth
- Touchscreen
- Battery
- G-Sensors (Device Orientation)
- Micro-SD Reader (Thus the D drive)

I am able to control the device via keyboard and mouse connected via a Micro-USB adapter.

So I went ahead and downloaded them from [HPs official site](https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/hp-stream-tablets/model/7482041). However, the installations seem to fail or the drivers end up not working. What do I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the drivers requiere Visual C++ Redistributable Packages that install certain run-time components. Depending on which HP Stream Generation another Package is required:

- For 7 (and up) use [Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-nz/download/details.aspx?id=48145), make sure to get the x86 version!
- For older version this might not work try an [older redistributable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170).

You will need to use the [compatibility troubleshooter](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/make-older-apps-or-programs-compatible-with-windows-783d6dd7-b439-bdb0-0490-54eea0f45938) to successfully install the redistributable successfully. It should recommend using setting for *Windows 8* (which is the version of windows this device was originally released with), if not select so manually.

After that and restarting, you must install the drivers one by one as admin and using [compatibility troubleshooter](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/make-older-apps-or-programs-compatible-with-windows-783d6dd7-b439-bdb0-0490-54eea0f45938) on each. Once the driver for Wi-Fi is installed successfully, you can also update Windows 10 to the latest version ( May take a couple of individual updates), by that point all remaining drivers should install successfully and work as intended.

Do note that due to the limited resources of this tablet, this will take a lot of time, when not using the Micro-USB port for keyboard and mouse you should plug in a charger, as the battery will drain under the load of install rather quick.